# YamlValidationException: Failed to validate 'domain.yml' while running rasa train

Tags: python, chatbot, rasa

I am getting the following error when I run `rasa train` -

```
YamlValidationException: Failed to validate '/home/suraj/Desktop/rasa hotel chatbot/domain.yml'. Please make sure the file is correct and all mandatory parameters are specified. Here are the errors found during validation
```

I have already checked the yaml file on two different websites for validity and they both show it as a valid yaml file. I checked all other answers on rasa forums and stack overflow but all of them had some syntax error as a solution. I have checked that all intents, responses, slots, entities are listed in my domain.yml.
Is anyone able to understand why this error is coming while training using rasa ?

Comment: Please let me know if I should upload my yaml file as well...it's my first time posting a question on stackoverflow.